# Deploying website on Window Azure

Tags: azure

I know that we can create website in java and deploy it on azure, but that can be done by creating an azure's cloud service. But I do not want to create cloud service( i.e. web role). I just want to create normal website (in java) and deploy it on azure.

Based on my current knowledge, this might not be possible. If not, what are the reasons that azure allows us to create java's cloud service but not website.

Thanks In Advace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of 3 offerings:
1. Website
2. Cloud Service
3. Virtual machines

In 1st and 2nd option, behind the walls, azure provides VM with windows operating system.

In case of 2nd option, you can upload JDK, Tomcat or other required infrastructure for your deployment. Which means we can create Java appliation.

But for website (1st offering), You do not get choice to upload/install anything apart from your binaries. Which means only those deployment can work which rely of default settings (like window OS and IIS). That is the reason that Java application would not work in this offering. But asp.net/node.js works.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Azure websites now supports Java web applications - check it out - http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-java-get-started/ - you use the default JDK 7 with Tomcat 7.0.50 or Jetty 9.1.0 OR you can even upload your own web container and configure it as per your requirements. Please refer to the link above.